# Symfony - Redirect on onSecurityAuthenticationSuccess

Tags: php, symfony

How can I return a response redirect in the onSecurityAuthenticationSuccess method?

```
public function onSecurityAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationEvent $event)
{
    $finalDestination= sprintf('%s?%s=false', $this->destination, self::PARAM_MATCH_SESSION);

    return new RedirectResponse($finalDestination);
}
```

In my code the redirect doesn't work. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Show the contents of finalDestination

Comment: This is the finalDestination value : `/my-account`

Comment: Are you getting an error? Have you tried using UrlGeneratorInterface?

Comment: no, I don't get an error. it's just that the request is forwarded to the controller and not redirected to finalDestination

Comment: Are you sure that your custom Authenticator is connected and working? Have you specified it in your security.yaml?

Comment: Debug and make sure that onSecurityAuthenticationSuccess is actually called.

Comment: yeah i am sure. i have debug it